# RavenDb: Join data with index

Tags: ravendb

In my database I have a list of cases:

```
{ Id: 1, Owner: "guid1", Text: "Question1" }
{ Id: 2, Owner: "guid1", Text: "Question2" }
{ Id: 3, Owner: "guid2", Text: "Question3" }
```

When querying for data I would also like to have (in my index, result) number of cases each Owner has. So I created a map/reduce index on this collection:

```
public class RelatedCases
{
    public Guid Owner { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class RelatedCaseIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<RelatedCases>
{
    public RelatedCaseIndex()
    {
        AddMap<CaseDocument> (c => c.Select(a => new { a.Owner, Count = 1 }));

        Reduce = result => result
            .GroupBy(a => a.Owner)
            .Select(a => new 
            { 
                Owner = a.Key, 
                Count = a.Sum(b => b.Count)
            });
    }
}
```

Now I just have no idea how to produce a query to include the data from the index. Based on documentation I tried something like:

```
session.Query<CaseDocument>().Customize(a => a.Include ...)
```

or TransformResults on a CaseIndex, which didn't work out properly.

I know I could just requery raven to get me list of all RelatedCases in a separate query, but I would like to do it in one round-trip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't query for Cases and join the result with the map/reduce index on the fly. That's just not how it works, because *every* query will run against an index, so what you are really asking is joining two indexes. This is something you need to do upfront.

In other words - put all the information you want to query upon into your map/reduce index. You can then run the query on this index and *.Include()* the documents that you are also interested in.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you need a MultiMap index, a simple MapReduce index will suffice for this.

You can then query it like so:

```
session.Query<RelatedCases, RelatedCaseIndex>();
```

This will bring back a list of RelatedCases with the owner and count.

Comment: Yea, I know, this is just a simplified case where I left just one map.